# talend 7.3.1 how do I add jdbc or sqlserver support to a route?

Tags: maven, jdbc, routes, apache-camel, talend

```
Starting job CalixKafkaClient at 17:03 17/08/2021.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3434
[statistics] connected
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route CalixKafkaClient_cKafka_1 at: >>> To[jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.205:1433;databaseName=SAR;user=kafkauser;password=kafkapassword;] <<< in route: Route(CalixKafkaClient_cKafka_1)[[From[kafka:quickstart-even... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: jdbc://sqlserver://192.168.100.205:1433;databaseName=SAR;user=kafkauser;password=kafkapassword; due to: No component found with scheme: jdbc
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route CalixKafkaClient_cKafka_1 at: >>> To[jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.205:1433;databaseName=SAR;user=kafkauser;password=kafkapassword;] <<< in route: Route(CalixKafkaClient_cKafka_1)[[From[kafka:quickstart-even... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: jdbc://sqlserver://192.168.100.205:1433;databaseName=SAR;user=kafkauser;password=kafkapassword; due to: No component found with scheme: jdbc
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1826)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:136)
    at org.apache.camel.main.Main.doStart(Main.java:139)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:170)
    at jmddr4.calixkafkaclient_0_1.CalixKafkaClient.run(CalixKafkaClient.java:196)
    at jmddr4.calixkafkaclient_0_1.CalixKafkaClient.runJobInTOS(CalixKafkaClient.java:292)
    at jmddr4.calixkafkaclient_0_1.CalixKafkaClient.main(CalixKafkaClient.java:262)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route CalixKafkaClient_cKafka_1 at: >>> To[jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.205:1433;databaseName=SAR;user=kafkauser;password=kafkapassword;] <<< in route: Route(CalixKafkaClient_cKafka_1)[[From[kafka:quickstart-even... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: jdbc://sqlserver://192.168.100.205:1433;databaseName=SAR;user=kafkauser;password=kafkapassword; due to: No component found with scheme: jdbc
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1352)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:212)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1139)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3736)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3439)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$4.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3247)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$4.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3243)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3266)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3243)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3159)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:133)
    ... 6 more
```

Here's the URI on the destination endpoint of the mediation route. The route payload body contains the full sql statement I want to execute, so I think this should work:

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.205:1433;databaseName=SAR;user=kafkauser;password=kafkapassword;"
```

I found this dependency and put added it to what I think is the pom file, but I don't know anything about maven or how routes compile or how these xml files work. I put it inside

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But it didn't make any difference. Could the version number be wrong? I think it will just skip it if it doesn't match. How do I find my version? Nvm I found my version number 2.24.2 and swapped it in, but it still didn't work.

So in Talend, Project Properties, where does the dependency go specifically? I thought I found it but I kept digging and it looks like a whole bunch of screens with xml files including some maybe route specific.